# JSON file to wide format in R

Tags: r, json, unnest

Is there a way to unnest wider a JSON file without having to know every aspect of the structure? I've [asked and received an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72052655/unnest-unlist-column-with-variable-lengths-in-r?noredirect=1#comment127523702_72052655), but when trying with what I thought would be the same JSON structure I am running into issues.

My dput output is too large for here (I've tried to capture enough of the variability of the lists generated), so I've just put into a google doc that can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/152x8oLhusUog5Wo8LGvejqk7F_uhbXelgPtiGHoC3gg/edit?usp=sharing).

This seems to start the process off...

```
wide_df <- json_df %>% 
  map_if(is.data.frame, list) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

...but I'm stuck how to unnest `tagEvents.tagResource` and `tagEvents.tagAttributes`

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly as all get out but unnests wider and I can clean up from there.

```
wide_json <- json_df %>% 
  purrr::map_if(is.data.frame, list) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  tibble::as_tibble() %>%
  tidyr::unnest(tagEvents.tagResource) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(., x = purrr::map(tagEvents.tagAttributes, unlist)) %>%  
  tidyr::unnest_wider(x, names_repair = 'universal')
```